# Why is my quiche weeping?

Tags: baking, custard, quiche

A quiche that I've made for years with no problems is now seeping a ridiculous amount of liquid. The ingredients include bacon, shredded swiss, onion (small amount, finely diced), eggs, half and half, salt, pepper and cayenne. I've made it the same way for ages so the fact that it is now so wet is a puzzle. I blind bake the crust but with the amount of liquid that is seeping, it isn't helping. Just to get an idea of the amount of liquid that I'm dealing with, I made a small version in an 8" oval baker and did not use a crust. After taking out a small portion (about 1/4), I let the dish sit and within 20 minutes I had 2-3 tablespoons of liquid pooling on the bottom of the dish.

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you changed oven recently?

Comment: If you cook an egg dish for too long the proteins will over coagulate and excessive moisture loss is the result.

Comment: Even if you've been making it the same for years, it's possible that the termostat in your oven is failing, and keeping things a little too hot (leading to overcooking, as mentioned above)

Comment: That was my thought as well. Or I also wondered if you have moved and perhaps live in a different elevation or climate that could require you to adjust your measurements a bit.

Comment: That must be the issue. I will try taking it out earlier and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you overcook it?  Overcooking will often cause eggs to weep not-insignificant amounts of liquid.

You can see this trivially if you overcook scrambled eggs - you'll get essentially "egg curds in soup".